# Set with lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I can connect the dots of a data file by including `with lines` in the `plot` command. Is there a way to set this fixed (I was hoping for `set with lines`) so I don't have to explicitly include it in every call of `plot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
set style data line
```

to achieve this. Similar options are also available for functions

```
set style function boxes
```